# Movie about a girl who had another different life when she dreamed

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I saw this movie a while ago in TV (I think it's a movie, but I'm not sure if it was a series episode, or a short-film), and I don't even remember in which language (not sure if English, because is not my main language).

I remember it as a horror movie. Here are the details:

- The protagonist was a young adult girl
- In the "reality world" when she was awake, she was a blonde and had a boyfriend and a "good life"
- Whenever she slept she had this "nightmares" of her being a different person (brunette even)
- The "Nightmare world" was bleak, depressing, dark, etc.
- In the "Nightmare world" she worked at a Morgue, with a big fat rude woman
- I even remember a scene where the fat woman broke the penis of a dead man in a gurney (or a morgue table, idk)
- In the "Nightmare world" the protagonist always was literally beaten up when she awoke, to her confusion. Later (using a camera to record herself sleeping) she is shocked to find out that during the night, crawl out from under her bed and raped her
- At the very end, she realizes that the "Nightmare world" she experienced when she slept was really her real world, and the "good happy life" she thought was her real world, was only her dreams...

Surprisingly I've never been able to find this movie writing every permutation of these details in Google... as my last resort, I created an account in this community only to find this, which is eating me from inside...

But I promise I'll pay my debt helping other people in the community if you can help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the plot of [Dark Corners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Corners) from 2006 with Thora Birch.

> Birch plays two characters, alternating between them each time she falls asleep, each of whom believes that the other is a dream. The first of them, Karen Clarke, is a mortuary worker who awakes to find that she has injuries which she does not recall receiving, and the second is Susan Hamilton, an office worker who is preparing to undergo artificial insemination. As time passes Clarke's world becomes increasingly nightmarish, with a corpse coming to life on her table and a serial killer stalking her, and the line between the two worlds becomes increasingly fragile.

She's blonde in the 'better' reality and brunette in the 'nightmare' world. Here's the trailer:

Comment: YOU ARE MY HEROOOO